# Uninitialized variable in access_log

Tags: nginx

I have the following config file:

```
    geo $log_ip {
        X.X.X.X 0;
        default 1;
    }


    map $request_uri $loggable {
        ~/app 0;
        default 1;
    }


    server {
        server_name www.example.com
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        
        set $logging 1;    
        if ( $log_ip = 0 ) {
            set $logging 0;
        }
        if ( $loggable = 0 ) {
            set $logging 0;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$logging;
        ...
```

I often get a warning similar to this one:

```
2020/09/23 08:29:10 [warn] 8#8: *364785 using uninitialized "logging" variable while logging request, client: Y.Y.Y.Y, server: www.example.com, request: "anything", host: "X.X.X.X"
```

As I set $logging 1 in the same context as access_log, how could it be uninitialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that Nginx evaluates the `access_log` directive in an earlier phase than those of the rewrite module (i.e. `set`, `if`, `rewrite` and `return`).

You may be able to eliminate the `set` and `if` statements by using a different `default` clause in the second `map` block.

For example:

```
geo $log_ip {
    X.X.X.X 0;
    default 1;
}
map $request_uri $loggable {
    ~/app 0;
    default $log_ip;
}

server {
    ...
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$loggable;
    ...
}
```